# Unable to modify authentication credential using Jersey 2.x when the client has been already created

Tags: java, authentication, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have followed the documentation of Jersey 2.x to authenticate any request and following is my code snippet.

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basicBuilder()
    .nonPreemptive()
    .credentials("user", "password")
    .build();

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.register(feature) ;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

Now let say i want to update the username, even if i do the same register of features with new username, i am still getting the username which is set earlier. How can i update the value of a already registered commonconfig for jersey client 2.x?

Comment: You can register the Feature with the WebTarget instead of the Client. Each new WebTarget you get from the Client can have it's own whole new set of providers and properties.

Comment: yeah, i have also done that way. overriding through creating separate webtarget for each request.